# How to print out PVOID variable in pascal to the screen

Tags: pointers, pascal

im trying to print out a pvoid variable to the screen from a pascal program, in c i would use `0x%p`, but in pascal, i dont know how ...
i tried something like this :
`writeln('[+] Address : ', Address);  {in which pAddress is the address to print}`
but it produced an error, im using *Lazarus IDE v2.2.2*

Comment: i print such variables cz its very helpful while debugging, instead of looking for the variable's local value in the ide debugger

Answer (score 1):

```
 writeln(format('Address: %p',[address]));
```

Format is in unit sysutils.

Comment: Using `sysBackTraceStr` supplied in the `system` unit is an alternative conversion function without pulling in big dependencies.

Comment: Sysutils is a pretty standard unit.

Comment: Kudos. Easiest form to print this type. Thanks!